# How to evaluate the contents of an each loop

Tags: erb

Here's the setup:

I have a data folder full of yaml files, each of which contains metadata about a post. In my .erb template, I'm looping through all of these with a simple each.do loop.

Now, what I want to do, rather than print every yaml file in that folder, is to only print those where the .yaml content contains an exact string.

Is this possible?

--
For example, let's say I have this structure for data

```
-data
--blogposts
---post1.yaml
---post2.yaml
...
---post100.yaml
```

and then, for each post#.yaml, for sake of simplicity, let's say it looks like this:

```
---
:id: 1
:title: my example title
:postCategory:
  - :id: 1
    :categoryTitle:
      :Business
```

And in my template, the loop to grab ALL posts obviously looks like:

```
<% data.blogposts.each do |id, post| %>
    *display stuff*
<% end %>
```

What I really want is to evaluate each .yaml file within "blogposts", check to see if there is a categoryTitle item that matches a string (let's say Business here), and if so, output as an item in the loop. The goal is that I could use this on each "category page" and dynamically just pull in posts who's category is being requested.

Comment: Can you provide a brief example of the yml files maybe 2 that should be included and 1 that should not and only to the extent that the data shown will adequately describe the problem?

Comment: Well, you will have to loop (somehow) through every file just to identify which ones contain that exact string, so you won't avoid looping all of them. Please share an example of your code, so we can get a better understanding of your problem.

Comment: @engineersmnky - added better description, thanks.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you are keeping post meta in separate file? If not then I think you can keep all the file on one yml file and loop over those data to find your expected data.

Comment: @Engr.HasanuzzamanSumon - Thanks for the comment. Yes I am using Contentful API to return content items - each entry is returned as a unique .yaml file so I need to be able to evaluate the contents of each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Enumerable#grep](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep), for given `category`

```
<% data.blogposts.each do |id, post| %>
    if File.readlines("#{post.name}.yaml").grep(/#{category}/).size > 0
        *display stuff*
    end
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks - this got me most of the way there.  
  
`<% if File.readlines("path/to/file/#{post.id}.yaml").grep(/#{category}$/).size > 0 %>  
<% end %>`

Answer (score 0):

I will go with something like this:

1. Check the `yaml` file when i receive it and search for `categoryTitle`.
2. Add the file name to a `master.yaml` file.
3. Read `master.yaml` to get the file name of all files i want to display.

This way you don't loop every time in all your files, you just go through one file to identify the ones that you really need to open.

So your folder structure will have one more file, for example:

```
-data
--master.yaml
--blogposts
---post1.yaml
---post2.yaml
...
---post100.yaml
```

And the `master.yaml` file structure may look like this:

```
:business:
  :post1.yaml
  :post3.yaml
:othertitle:
  :post2.yaml
  :post5.yaml
```

Just check `master.yaml` for the files with the title you want (e.g. `business`) and loop through those files only (instead of looping all files every time).